# Whitelist Server in SpamAssassin

Tags: exim, spamassassin, sa-exim

Iss possible add a server with various subdomains in SpamAssassin Whitelist, like *.example.com?

This is the host instance with subdomains:

```
email@example-2.com.br hm1480-p-60.example.com [IP-ADDRES-1]
email@example-3.com.br mail28157.hm1315.example.com [IP-ADDRESS-2]
email@example.net mail926.hm1479.example.com [IP-ADDRESS-3]
```

I looked for information in the SpamAssassin documentation, but it only tells how to block for a server and a sender domain.

https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.2.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html#whitelist_and_blacklist_options

Answer (score 0):

if you want to whitelist some sender addresses of messages sent by relays in *example.com* domain or any subdomain of *example.com* of use the following syntax:

```
whitelist_from_rcvd email@example-2.com.br example.com
whitelist_from_rcvd email@example-3.com.br example.com
whitelist_from_rcvd email@example.net example.com
```